# Rails Mass Assignment on Integer Value From a Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

All values coming from a web form are string. I have a class named `Announcement` which has a field `kind` and its data type is integer. On the model class I define an enum

```
enum kind: {
  event: 1,
  feature: 2
}
```

About mass assignment I have done it, no problem in general. The problem is when I'm doing this it will complain about `'1' is not a valid kind` because it's a string not an integer.

```
announcement=Announcement.new(announcement_params)
```

Is there any solution for this problem except manually set the value for the field?
Thank you

Comment: what is datatype of kind field in your migration?

Comment: and expose your `announcement_params` method

Comment: so every params is string type so you have to conver it

Comment: convert `params[:announcement][:kind].to_i` it will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

The answer just come to my mind, this is what i do to solve the problem

```
kind=params[:announcement][:kind].to_i
params[:announcement].delete(:kind)
params[:announcement].merge(kind: kind)
```

1. Get the `kind` param and convert it to an integer
2. Remove the `kind` which is a string from the params
3. Merge the new `kind` to the params

And the last is white listing parameters for mass assignment

Thank you @uzaif

Answer (score 0):

You can **redefine the setter for the `kind` attribute** in your `Announcement` model, like this:

```
# app/models/announcement.rb
def kind=(value)
  super(value.to_i)
  # or
  # super(Integer(value))
end
```

This converts the given value to integer first and then calls the original method defined by the `enum`. Note however, that `to_i` will convert anything, even non-numbers or `nil`s - these will be converted to `0`. So I'd advise to either never use `0` among your defined enum values or to use the `Integer(value)` form, which will raise an exception on non-numbers or `nil`s.

The setter allows mass assignment again:

```
Announcement.new(kind: '1')   # should be OK
```